# Is there a way to autocorrect the URL entered by client in play framework?

Tags: java, redirect, routes

Suppose I have a url in config file like

GET     /project/index         app.controller.showIndex()

Is there a way to redirect to this route if the user enters an incorrect URL in the browser, like /project or /project/ind, It should not show a 404 error message but redirect the user to the correct page i.e. /project/index.
I know that I can use redirect method, but is there any other way as redirect is used to redirect to an external page.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.